# Operator reversibility

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\phi(t)$ be a continuous on $[0,1]$ function that maps a segment $[0,1]$ into itself. I'm trying to find under what conditions on the function $\phi(t)$ the operator $(Ax)(t) = x(\phi(t))$ in the space $C[0, 1]$ has right inverse, left inverse, reversible. I know that the existence of an inverse function for a continuous function $\phi(t)$ is necessary for $\phi(t)$ to be strictly monotonic. But I'm unable to find the exact conditions for the existence of left, right inverse operators, can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: If $\varphi(t)$ is strictly monotonic and continuous then $A$ is right invertible. It is left invertible iff $\varphi([0,1])=[0,1].$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc As I understand it, in order for the operator to be left invertible, it is necessary that the $A^{-1}$ operator transform the function $x(\phi(t))$ in such a way that the values of $x(\phi(t))$ and $x(t)$ match, so $\phi([0, 1]) = [0, 1]$. In order for the operator to be right invertible, it is necessary that the function $\phi((A^{-1}x)(t))$ give an identical function, that is, it must be invertible, and therefore be strictly monotonic.

Comment: Yes. There is a restriction on the left invertibility, as $A$ is not injective if $\varphi([0,1])\subsetneq [0,1].$ For example if $x$ vanishes on $\varphi([0,1])$ then $Ax=0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks a lot! For some reason, I did not immediately understand that everything is quite simple

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I have a question, I didn’t understand how to prove that if $\phi([0, 1]) = [0, 1]$, then the operator is reversed from the left?

Comment: I will answer in $1$ hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\varphi$ is strictly monotonic and $\varphi([0,1])=[0,1].$ Then there exists the inverse function $\psi:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $\varphi(\psi(y))=y.$ The function $\psi$ is continuous by the inverse mapping theorem.
Let $(Bf)(y)=f(\psi(y)).$ Then $B$ is a bounded operator on $C[0,1]$ and
$$(BAf)(y)=B(Af)(y)=(Af)(\psi(y))=f(\phi(\psi(y)))=f(y)$$
Hence $BA=I,$ i.e.
$A$ is left invertible.
The condition $\varphi([0,1])=[0,1]$ is necessary for the left invertibility. Indeed
assume $\varphi([0,1])=[a,b]\subsetneq [0,1].$ Then either $a>0$ or $b<1.$ In each case there is a function $f\in C[0,1]$ such that $f\neq 0$ and $f(y)=0$ for $y\in [a,b].$ Then $(Af)(x)=f(\varphi(x))=0.$ Thus $f\in \ker A,$ therefore $A$ cannot be left invertible.

Concerning right invertibility, assume the function $\varphi$ is strictly monotonic and $\varphi([0,1])=[a,b].$ Then there exists a function $\psi:[a,b]\to [0,1]$ such that $\psi(\varphi(x))=x$ for $x\in [0,1].$ By the inverse mapping theorem the function $\psi$ is continuous. Let $(Bf)(y)=f(\psi(y)).$ Then $B$ is a bounded operator on $C[0,1]$ and
$$(ABf)(x)=A(Bf)(x)=Bf(\phi(x))=f(\psi(\phi(x)))=f(x)$$
Hence $AB=I$, i.e. $A$ is right invertible.

The assumption that $\varphi$ is strictly monotonic is necessary for the right invertibility. Indeed, assume $\varphi$ is not strictly monotonic. Then there exist $x_1,x_2\in [0,1]$ such that $\varphi(x_1)=\varphi(x_2).$ Hence
$(Af)(\varphi(x_1))=Af(\varphi(x_2)),$ which implies that $A$ is not surjective. Thus it is not right invertible.

The assumption that $\varphi$ is strictly monotonic is not necessary for the left invertibility. Indeed, let
$$\varphi(x)=\min\{2x,2-2x\},\quad 0\le x\le 1$$
and $\psi(y)={y\over 2}.$ Then
$$\varphi(\psi(y))=\min\{y,2-y\}=y,\quad 0\le y\le 1$$
Define $Bg(y)=g(\psi(y)).$ Then
$$BAf(y)=B(Af)(y)=Af(\psi(y))=f(\varphi(\psi(y)))=f(y)$$
Thus $BA=I.$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ryszard Szwarc's answer in the comments, I'm attaching the following solution: In order for the operator to be left invertible, it is necessary that the $A^{-1}$ operator transform the function $x(\varphi(t))$ in such a way that the values of $x(\varphi(t))$ and $x(t)$ match, so $\varphi([0,1])=[0,1]$. In order for the operator to be right invertible, it is necessary that the function $\varphi((A^{-1}x)(t))$ give an identical function, that is, it must be invertible, and therefore be strictly monotonic. Also, notice that if $A$ is not injective, then $\varphi([0,1]) ⊊ [0, 1]$, so exist $t \in [0, 1]$ such that $(Ax)(t) = 0$